# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.DataTable'?8

Tags: c#

I have to update "cad_assign" column while clicking submit button based on the selected state from the drop down list. While clicking submit button the value 1 should insert into cad_assign column.

Code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteDetailsDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteDetailsTableAdapter cd;
        cd = new SSiteDetailsDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteDetailsTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = cd.GetUpdateCadAssign(ddlState.SelectedValue); // error shown here
    }
```

Query1:

```
UPDATE tbl_site_details SET cad_assign = 1 WHERE (state1 = @state1)
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatee_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Assisgn" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Have int. Need DataTable. See other ["Cannot implicitly convert type"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Cannot+implicitly+convert+type%22) questions for what this means.

Comment: `GetUpdateCadAssign` is returning an int. I don't think that's what you really intend to do.

Comment: You method `GetUpdateCadAssign` apparently returns an int, you are trying to assign it to a variable of type `DataTable`.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand the downvote....

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you. Now I get values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given below code is working perfectly. Thank you all.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteDetailsDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteDetailsTableAdapter cd;
        cd = new SSiteDetailsDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteDetailsTableAdapter();
        cd.GetUpdateCadAssign(ddlState.SelectedValue);
    }
```